# Dynamically passing column name in ADO.NET

Tags: c#

```
string[] rowdetails = orderDS.Tables[0].Rows[j]["'"+column[k]+"'"] as string[];
```

Can a column name can be passed dynamically?  The code above is not working when I pass the column name.  Double quotes is the problem. I need to pass the column name there.

Answer (score 3):

[DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f2d84ta.aspx) has [multiple Item properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item.aspx) that you could use:

```
string[] rowdetails = orderDS.Tables[0].Rows[j][column[k]] as string[];
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - wouldn't rows[1][1] return a single string instead of a string array?

Comment: It returns `System.Object`. There could be anything stored in this cell but your remark is correct as a single string seems more realistic.

Comment: i tried that already. It returns null. we should enclose double quotes like ["column_name"]. While passing the dynamic column name i couldn't handle the double quotes. :-(